# Msal.IdToken is not a constructor while using MSAL version 0.1.3 in angularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using this method to decode token and get expiry of token,
var decode = Msal.IdToken(localStorage["msal.idtoken"]);

I use this because I want to avoid add one more jwtdecode library of angularJS.
We use MSAL for Active directory login functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to get a hold of the id token one of two ways using MSAL v.0.1.3.

The first was directly from sessionStorage:

```
let idtoken = sessionStorage.getItem("msal.idtoken")
```

The second was to store it upon successful login:

```
let idToken = "";
msalClient.loginPopup("myclientid",null)
 .then(token => {
     idToken = token;
  });
```

The problem is that neither of these methods deals with token expiration -- but I haven't found anything in the MSAL library that will return the current id token.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't read your question close enough.  The response I have will require the use of jwtdecode to access the claims.  I'm not currently aware of anything in the v.01.3 library that will give you access to the idtoken or its claims